# Declaring variables and using getElementById to print Hello World

Tags: javascript, html

The assignment is such that I have to declare variables 1(Hello), 2(world) and result,  and create a string in p element using getElementById/innerHTML. The result should also printed in console log. I've tried several combinations such as this, but I have no idea how to go from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p id= "tulos">Haloo maailma!</p>

    <script>

   var tulos = document.getElementById("tulos").innerHTML "Haloo";
   var tulos = document.getElementById("tulos").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tulos").innerHTML+ "maailma!";
   console.log(tulos);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what do you need, but my guess is you want to print variable to a p tag and also able to console it

```
<p id="target"></p>
<script>
   let var1 = 'hello';
   let var2 = 'world';
   let result = var1 +' '+var2;
   let target = document.getElementById('target');
   target.innerHTML = result;
   console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: This is so close to what I once had. Thanks! I'll tried this and it worked! Thanks a bunch again.